# Must the operator for a semigroup be defined for all arguments?

Tags: haskell

Is the example below a correct definition of a semigroup?

```
instance Semigroup (CurrencyAmount Fixed2) where
  (<>) (CurrencyAmount a c) (CurrencyAmount _ EMPTY) = CurrencyAmount a c
  (<>) (CurrencyAmount _ EMPTY) (CurrencyAmount a c) = CurrencyAmount a c
  (<>) (CurrencyAmount a c1) (CurrencyAmount b c2) | c1 == c2 = CurrencyAmount (a + b) c1
  (<>) _ _ = error "currency mismatch"
```

Comment: The operator should be *associative*, so you can aim to proof that, and then it is a semigroup.

Comment: the operator is associative int this example for valid inputs but the <> operator (or function) is not total in this case and I do not know if this is relevant for the prove or not.

Comment: The definition of `CurrencyAmount` would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is a matter of semantics. The formal and classical mathematical definition of a Semigroup `(A,<>)` does requires `<>` to be a function `<>:A×A→A`, therefore total. But what is your set `A`? You need to establish some (naive) set theoretical based semantics for the (Haskell) types and functions you're working with.

- If the denotation of your types are carrier sets that include `⊥` as an element, then your Haskell functions will be interpreted as total mathematical functions. In this case you just have to make sure the required laws hold for all elements including `⊥`. And in your case they do.
- If instead you consider a model of sets (without `⊥`) and partial functions, then to match the classic formal mathematical definition of `Semigroup` you'd need to make sure `<>` is total in that setting. And in your case it isn't.

I don't know whether there is a fixed convention. The second, stricter interpretation seems preferable. But the first is a sensible generalisation.

That said have you considered the possibility of using GADTs to distinguish between different currencies at the type level?

Comment: Well one can add a dollar to a pound, and have a dollar *and* a pound. (Like a vector space of currencies).

Comment: I don't think including bottom is a useful approach in practice, as it's hard to manipulate diverging computations. Can you write a unit test that verifies `bottom <> bottom == bottom`?

Comment: You could say the same for any property involving `⊥` though, including strictness. Furthermore, it's not that simple to avoid `⊥`. Consider `<>` defined on function types. The resulting laws establish equalities on (partial) functions. The Semigroup module itself provides the instance `Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)`  where `f <> g = \x -> f x <> g x`.

Comment: I can, and I usually do ;) One can *reason* about the bottom, but one cannot *work* with it. It is not a useful value --- a program that tries to evaluate it is broken. A program can pass unevaluated bottoms around, but since it cannot look at them, one could replace these bottoms by any other value without affecting the meaning of the program.

Comment: I think I like the vector of currencies approach best.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's valid.

Most of the lawful type classes in Haskell (e.g. `Semigroup`, `Monoid`, `Functor`, `Monad`, etc.) derive their laws from mathematics (e.g. category theory).

Mathematics is based on axioms; that is, assertions about the underlying fabric of numbers, geometry, and similar. By definition, axioms can't be proven, but you usually accept them because they make intuitive sense (e.g. the Peano axioms). In a sense, mathematics is built on a foundation of intuition.

The reason that type classes like the above are lawful is that the laws ensure that the instances behave like you'd expect them to behave.

In Haskell, there's great emphasis on being able to **reason about the code**, mostly by just looking at the type signatures of functions. One reason you, as a reader, can feel confident about doing this is that whenever a lawful type class is involved, you know that it'll behave in a non-surprising manner.

Most mathematical functions are **total** (there are exceptions, e.g. division by zero, but exceptions should be drawn from mathematics itself). In light of the above, I'd argue that there's a strong implicit expectation that a type class that derives its laws from mathematics is expected to be total.

The above instance isn't total, which means that it'll behave in a surprising manner for certain inputs. I wouldn't consider it a valid `Semigroup` instance.

Comment: Yeah. Division.

Comment: @n.m. What about division?

Comment: Is it total? What's its domain? To what Haskell type does said domain correspond?

Comment: @n.m. It's not uncommon in mathematics that functions can be ["undefined" at points not in its domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics)). Do we consider the zero denominator part of the division function's domain?

Comment: @n.m. Not that I don't get your point. In Haskell, division is clearly not total, so it does invalidate my argument. Do you, however, find the OP instance valid?

Comment: That's what I'm asking *you*. Do we consider the zero denominator part of the division function's domain? If we do, then it's a partial function. If we don't, then its totality is irrelevant for Haskell, because we cannot adequately represent its domain as a Haskell type.

Comment: No I don't think it's valid, not at all. But it's not because mathematical functions must be total in Haskell, as there are exceptions to this rule. We don't expect division to be total for all (or any) instances of Num for example. It's because we always expect *this particular function* to be total, no exceptions.

Comment: @n.m. I admit that exceptions exist. I also agree that we expect `<>` to be total. How can the OP tell? With my answer, I've attempted to provide a heuristic.

Comment: Your answer is mostly great, just instead of saying that all math functions should be total, say that most math function should be total, and exceptions should be drawn from math itself (e.g. division is not defined for zero denominator because field laws say so, not because our particular field has problems with division so we just leave it undefined).

Comment: @n.m. Good suggestion; I've edited my answer. Thank you.